# Why do some .js files stop working when downloaded to localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax, pdf.js

I have a problem that when I use a code that links to a .js file available online, the code works fine but if I try to save this .js file on localhost and then link to it, the code doesn't work. For example, This code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

works fine, but when I downloaded http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML to localhost and then link to it by changing

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MathJax.js"></script>
```

This code stopped working. I encountered the same problem with pdf.js. This problem doesn't happen with every .js file. For example I downloaded jquery and jquery-ui files to localhost and they worked fine.  Also, when I link to my own script files that I wrote the code works fine too.

I have checked that MathJax.js is in the js folder and its with other js files like jquery.js and usually when I use jquery.js I just use the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

My question is: Am I doing something wrong or do these files only work online?

Comment: You're probably linking to it incorrectly locally. Try specifying the full file path in the src tag.

Comment: I tried http://localhost/mysite/js/MathJax.js and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Debug :

1. Open chrome developer tools by right clicking on page and doing
   inspect element or view > developer > developer tools.
2. Navigate to network.You might have to refresh page after going to network.
3. Do you see file loads successfully?
4. If it's red then that means it didn't load correctly.
5. Right click and open it in new tab and verify path.

Update :

MathJax is a package so you have to link entire package rather than just individual file. Refer here http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#downloading-and-installing-mathjax

Comment: can you still try to open it in new tab and find out if it has all your library code?

Comment: You mean its working now and your problem is solved?

Comment: No, I mean that js file loads in the new tap but still my page doesn't work. I think there is an extension missing because when I refreshed my website page a label in the bottom came up saying "failed to load localhost/mysite/js/extensions/MathZoom.js"

Comment: yeah maybe mathjax is depending on it. OH yes mathjax is a package and not just individual js file.

Comment: The "update" is on the right track. MathJax consists of several thousand files (though depending on your configuration and browser support requirements, most can be dropped) ; in particular MathJax ships several input and output components and webfonts. MathJax.js only provides the base infrastructure for configuring and loading of components.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the link to the javascript file is correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="js/MathJax.js">
    </script>
```

The above script says the file MathJax.js is inside js directory AND the js directory is at the same level as the file you are linking from

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="./js/MathJax.js">
</script>
```

The ./ gives the file a relative startpoint. However, if the javascript is not in a folder entitled "js" which is sitting in the same folder as your html, this won't work.

The other solution is to build the entire absolute file path to the file in your tag, and end with "/MathJax.js".